# Hyperlinking a button

Tags: ios, swift, url, button, ibaction

I am trying to create a button that goes to a link when pressed using Swift 3. When I run the app and click the button, nothing happens. Here is the code for the button's `@IBAction`:

```
@IBAction func facebookButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.facebook.com/MatchWear-1638094356470603/info?tab=overview"){
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check some things with the debugger....  Does your method get called?  if yes, does the "open" statement execute?

Comment: Put a break point when you create your URL to check if UIApplication.shared.open(url) is called.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming that you are pretty sure that the `@IBAction` is connected to your button**, it should looks like this:

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://www.facebook.com/MatchWear-1638094356470603/info?tab=overview") , UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
} else {
    // invalid URL...
}
```

Hope this helped.